# Data getting inserted into different column than it should in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql, cassandra-3.0

```py
def insert_data(self):
    insert_sql = self.session.prepare("INSERT INTO customer 
       (ID ,Name,Gender , Age , Region ,Job, Balance ) 
       VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)")
    batch = BatchStatement()
    batch.add(insert_sql, ('100000051', 'Abhishek', 'Male','20', 'India','Engineer','199992.9'))
    #Add any new value if you want to insert in cassandra table
    self.session.execute(batch) 
    self.log.info('Batch Insert Completed')
```

But data is getting inserted into wrong column:

```
id        | region           | age   | balance   | gender | job          | name
    -----------+------------------+-------+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------
100000025 |          England |    38 |  20505.32 | Female | White Collar |  Jennifer
200000017 |         Scotland |    31 |  10356.31 | Female |        Other |     Grace
300000015 |            Wales |    36 |   2846.03 | Female |        Other | Madeleine
200000029 |         Scotland |    50 |   20516.1 |   Male |  Blue Collar |     Lucas
100000019 |          England |    40 |  65534.69 |   Male |  Blue Collar |   William
100000050 |         Engineer | India |      20   |   Male |     199992.9 |  Abhishek
```

what is wrong with above code?

Comment: What is your table definition?  I tried recreating it based on what I see, used your exact code, and it put the values in the correct columns.

Comment: Also, why are you using a batch statement?  You're only writing a single row to a single table.  Batch in Cassandra works _very_ differently than in the relational world.  Plus, you take a 30% performance hit just for using it.

Comment: I am supposed to add multiple row using this code that's why I have used batch statement.

Comment: /def create_table(self):
  c_sql = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer(ID text,Name text,Gender text, Age text, region text,Job text, Balance text, PRIMARY KEY(ID, Region));
     """
  self.session.execute(c_sql)/

Comment: BATCH in Cassandra is not meant to be used to add multiple rows to one table.  It’s to add one row to multiple tables.  Bulk writes should be sent one at a time, asynchronously with awaitable futires.